# Unable to manually install the http_proxy module

Tags: drush

We are behind a corporate firewall, so the first thing I do with new Drupal 7 is to manually download, unzip, & use Drush to enable the http_proxy module ($ drush en http_proxy.) Once that is configured, I can then run cron, do drush dl xxxx modules etc. without firewall issues.

For my first Drupal 8 venture, I updated to Drush 8.1.10; downloaded the Drupal 8 gzip file from the http_proxy project, then copied & unzipped the file to /modules/contrib/http_proxy/ > on my server.

When I try to enable the http_proxy contrib module, I get the following loop -- never get the module enabled.

Is there some special trick with Drupal 8 for manual module installation?

```
$ pwd
/apps/drupal-sites/TEMS/modules/contrib

$ cls
[drupal@drupaldev1 contrib]$ drush --version
Drush Version   :  8.1.10 

$ pwd
/apps/drupal-sites/TEMS/modules/contrib
$ ll -R
.:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 drupal 4096 Nov 17  2012 http_proxy/    

./http_proxy:
total 36
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drupal  2446 Nov 17  2012 http_proxy.admin.inc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drupal   308 Nov 17  2012 http_proxy.info
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drupal  2015 Nov 17  2012 http_proxy.module
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drupal 18092 Sep 17  2011 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drupal   735 Nov 17  2012 README.txt

$ 
$ drush en http_proxy
http_proxy was not found.                                                                                           [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                  [ok]
http_proxy
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
Install location /apps/drupal-sites/TEMS//modules/contrib/http_proxy     already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n): n
Skip installation of http_proxy to /apps/drupal-    sites/TEMS//modules/contrib/http_proxy.                         [warning]
http_proxy was not found.                                                                                           [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                  [ok]
http_proxy
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
Install location /apps/drupal-sites/TEMS//modules/contrib/http_proxy     already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n): y
Project http_proxy (8.x-1.0) downloaded to /apps/drupal-    sites/TEMS//modules/contrib/http_proxy.                 [success]
Project http_proxy contains 0 modules: .
http_proxy was not found.                                                                                           [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                  [ok]
http_proxy
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
Install location /apps/drupal-sites/TEMS//modules/contrib/http_proxy     already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n): y
Project http_proxy (8.x-1.0) downloaded to /apps/drupal-    sites/TEMS//modules/contrib/http_proxy.                 [success]
Project http_proxy contains 0 modules: .
http_proxy was not found.                                                                                           [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                  [ok]
http_proxy
Would you like to download them? (y/n): n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the files for the [8.x-1-x branch](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/http_proxy/tree/?h=8.x-1.x), I noticed that those files are essentially the files for Drupal 7, not Drupal 8. Even the https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/http_proxy-8.x-1.0.tar.gz archive contains file for Drupal 7.

One of the differences between the versions for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 is that for Drupal 8 the [http_proxy.info](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/http_proxy/tree/http_proxy.info) file should be replaced from a http_proxy.info.yml file.
Since Drush uses the content of that file to understand if the directory contains a module, and to retrieve the information about that module, without any .info.yml file with the information about the http_proxy module Drush is not able to find it in the already downloaded modules. That is why it keeps saying it doesn't find it.

So, to answer your question: No, you don't need any particular trick to download and install modules on Drupal 8. It just happens the module has not been really ported to Drupal 8, and Drush gets confused.

Comment: Thank you-- that makes perfect sense!  I see that the module hasn't been updated (neither D7 nor D8 paths) since 2013!
I am new to Drupal 8 -- just looked at the '8.x ' text in the http_proxy.info file-- and didn't really notice that there was no YAML file.
So.... http_proxy really isn't ready for Drupal 8!  
I wonder if anyone can suggest an alternative approach to running D8 behind an institutional HTTP proxying firewall?!?!

Comment: I see that the issue of the missing .YAML file for the 8.x.x branch of this module was already raised by someone around February 2017... 
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/http_proxy 

I will presume that the proxy's .module file is solid PHP; will attempt to add my first module .YAML file, and report back if I can get this to fly...